# Google Cloud ml-engine fails at loading libnccl

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

Hello tensorflow and Google Cloud users/developers,

When I submit a job that demands GPU support, ml-engine fails while loading libnccl.so.2 file. Here is the output from gcloud logs:

```
INFO    2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0        Error reported to Coordinator: libnccl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0        Traceback (most recent call last):
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            "__main__", mod_spec)
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            exec(code, run_globals)
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/main/task.py", line 220, in <module>
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            main()
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/main/task.py", line 185, in main
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            valid_spec
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 471, in train_and_evaluate
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            return executor.run()
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 637, in run
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            getattr(self, task_to_run)()
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 674, in run_master
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            self._start_distributed_training(saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 788, in _start_distributed_training
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 354, in train
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1205, in _train_model
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            return self._train_model_distributed(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1316, in _train_model_distributed
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            self.config)
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/distribute.py", line 721, in call_for_each_tower
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            return self._call_for_each_tower(fn, *args, **kwargs)
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/python/mirrored_strategy.py", line 556, in _call_for_each_tower
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            return _call_for_each_tower(self, fn, *args, **kwargs)
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/python/mirrored_strategy.py", line 183, in _call_for_each_tower
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            coord.join(threads)
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 389, in join
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            raise value
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 297, in stop_on_exception
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            yield
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/python/mirrored_strategy.py", line 177, in _call_for_each_tower
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            **merge_kwargs)
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 661, in _distributed_apply
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            variable_scope.VariableAggregation.SUM, grads_and_vars)
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/distribute.py", line 776, in batch_reduce
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            return self._batch_reduce(aggregation, value_destination_pairs)
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/python/mirrored_strategy.py", line 628, in _batch_reduce
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            value_destination_pairs)
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/python/cross_tower_ops.py", line 243, in batch_reduce
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            return self._batch_reduce(aggregation, value_destination_pairs)
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/python/cross_tower_ops.py", line 597, in _batch_reduce
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            [v[0] for v in value_destination_pairs])
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/python/cross_tower_ops.py", line 631, in _batch_all_reduce
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            device_grad_packs)
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/python/cross_tower_utils.py", line 41, in aggregate_gradients_using_nccl
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            agg_grads = nccl.all_sum(single_grads)
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/nccl/python/ops/nccl_ops.py", line 49, in all_sum
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            return _apply_all_reduce('sum', tensors)
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/nccl/python/ops/nccl_ops.py", line 217, in _apply_all_reduce
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            _validate_and_load_nccl_so()
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/nccl/python/ops/nccl_ops.py", line 288, in _validate_and_load_nccl_so
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            _maybe_load_nccl_ops_so()
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/nccl/python/ops/nccl_ops.py", line 274, in _maybe_load_nccl_ops_so
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            resource_loader.get_path_to_datafile('_nccl_ops.so'))
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/util/loader.py", line 56, in load_op_library
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            ret = load_library.load_op_library(path)
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 60, in load_op_library
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0            lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename)
ERROR   2019-01-07 15:13:58 +0000   master-replica-0        tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: libnccl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Am I supposed to install nccl to ml-engine? I specify "tensorflow-gpu (>=1.12)" in required_packages field of setup.py. and my config.yaml file looks like this:

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: complex_model_m_gpu
  workerType: complex_model_m_gpu
  parameterServerType: large_model
  workerCount: 0
  parameterServerCount: 0
```

My quota allows me to use 4 K-80 devices on europe-west1 region.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: NCCL is missing in TensorFlow 1.12 on Cloud ML Engine now, and we are working on the backfilling. The ETA is two weeks. Can you use TensorFlow 1.11 for now? Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Well it seems that it still somehow fails with a weird message (NotConvertableToTensor or something like that); but at least not due to nccl stuff... By the way, it does not fail on a single gpu device. Anyway, thx for the reply. I'll figure out the other problem

Comment: This should have been solved already can you confirm?